# How to enter into this rulefor fluent validation only if textbox is empty

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I am using simple form fluent validations. How to enter into this rule only if it's Notes Textbox is empty and should return validation if that linq query returns a record.

If textbox is not empty it should not enter into this rule.

Here's what I have tried

```
RuleFor(i => i.Notes)
                .NotEmpty()
                .When((i) =>
                    {
                        bool result = false;

            result = _DAL.GetExists<EmployeeScheduleTypes>
                                    (q => q.Type == i.Type);


                        return result;
                    })
                .WithMessage("Notes is required");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension method `When` should be used for specifying condition when property validator should be run. In your case condition is not empty `Notes` property. And validation predicate should go to `Must` extension:

```
RuleFor(i => i.Notes)
    .Must(i => _DAL.GetExists<EmployeeScheduleTypes>(q => q.Type == i.Type))
    .When(i => String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Notes))
    .WithMessage("Notes is required");
```

This rule means: when Notes is empty then object should have existing type, otherwise set error for Notes property.

Comment: When Notes textbox is empty its not validating

Comment: @sgl no, it's validating. Your problem is elsewhere. Make sure `_DAL.GetExists<EmployeeScheduleTypes>(q => q.Type == i.Type)` returns false if you are expecting to see an error

Comment: Thank You So Much ..That's Fixed